# Do residuals have units?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, least-squares

I have residuals from a mass prediction equation developed from DOE.
When displaying these residuals on a graph or table do these have a unit of grams or no unit?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.

Comment: The residuals are in the same scale as your response variables..